# Error in setting custom font - Android

Tags: android, variables, fonts

For an Android widget I've been developing, I'm trying to use a custom font. I've looked up some tutorials on the internet, and I found several ways to do it. I chose one and tried to implement it, but I get an error and I can't figure out why. The technique uses a seperate class (of which I've posted the code below), to set the font. In this code I get an error at the customFont line in setCustomFont. It says that customFont cannot be resolved to a variable. Can anybody help me out as to why this is happening?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TypefacedTextView extends TextView {
private static final String TAG = "TextView";

public TypefacedTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public TypefacedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setCustomFont(context, attrs);
}

public TypefacedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setCustomFont(context, attrs);
}

private void setCustomFont(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TypefacedTextView);
    String customFontl = a.getString(R.styleable.TypefacedTextView_typeface);
    setCustomFont(ctx, customFont); //                      get an error here
    a.recycle();
}

public boolean setCustomFont(Context ctx, String asset) {
    Typeface tf = null;
    try {
    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), asset);  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not get typeface: " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }

    setTypeface(tf);  
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
 String customFontl = a.getString(R.styleable.TypefacedTextView_typeface);
 setCustomFont(ctx, customFont); //                      get an error here
```

Your variable is declared as `customFontl` (note final `l`), and you are trying to use it as `customFont`. I would guess the error is that `customFont` is not defined or something alike, as it is the case.

Comment: ok so that was just a typo, thanks for noticing that ;) . My code is now supposedly all good (according to eclipse) but when I launch my widget, it tells me it can't be displayed. This error must be in the custom font part, since it worked fine before i tried to use the custom font

Answer (score 0):

i have try this may it help you in this code my font is in asset/fonts folder 
if it is only in asseet than replace in code fonts/

```
  public class MyTextView extends TextView{

 public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
        rotate();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
        rotate();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
        rotate();
    }

    private void rotate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setSelected(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/TrajanPro-Regular.otf");
            setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }


}
```